# Why are the Configuration options not available in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, configuration, asp.net-2.0

I have a simple Web Handler project, and for some reason I cannot choose it's configuration either from the drop Down on the standard bar (It is greyed out), or from the Build Menu (there is no "Batch Build" or "Configuration Manager" menu entries for this one project).  All the rest of my projects work fine, and it is a fresh clean build of Visual Studio 2008 (although it is on Windows7 64 bit).  The project is fine on other computers (in that you can change configuration easily).  Anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try these. One of them is bound to work!

1. Reset Visual Studio. Running this in the .NET Command Prompt should do it:

   ```
   devenv /resetsettings
   ```

   This will reset Visual Studio back to factory settings and you should have your missing icons back.
2. Open up *Import/Export Settings* in the *Tools* menu and reset to General Development Settings.
3. Use the *Customize* option in the *Tools* menu and see if you can drag the features back in place.
4. Uninstall Visual Studio. Next, remove all the related registry keys that may not have been removed automatically. For example:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio
   ```

   Re-install Visual Studio and you should have the defaut layout back.

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me.  I didn't want to do a reset since it takes me all day to set up all the macros and everything the way I like it.

It turned out there's a setting that grays out the configuration dropdown. Tools\options\ under projects and solutions "Show Advanced Build Configurations"  I checked it and it fixed it.